# How to copy only value not use reference, or what I should do with this inside list reference?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I have written Smith-Waterman like algorithm and it is leaking

Here is my leaking fragment of code:

```
for row in range(1, n + 1):
    for col in range(1, m + 1):
        left = table[row][col - 1] - 1
        up = table[row - 1][col] - 1
        upLeft = table[row - 1][col - 1] + s(seq1[col - 1], seq2[row - 1])
        table[row][col] = max(left, up, upLeft)
```

The last line leaks.

How to copy only value not use reference, or what I should do with this inside list reference?

Other question is how to optimize this algorithm to use only 2 columns/rows, but it's not difficult probably. First I want to know why the code leaking.

Full code:

```
def smith_waterman(seq1, seq2):
"""
:rtype : float
:return: folat 
:param seq1: list of 0,1,2
:param seq2: list of 0,1,2
"""
m = len(seq1)
n = len(seq2)

def s(a, b):
    """

    :param a: 0,1,2
    :param b: 0,1,2
    :return: iteger
    """
    c = a + b
    if a == b:
        return 2
    elif c == 3:
        return 1
    elif c == 2:
        return 2
    else:
        return -1

# create empty table
table = []
for i in range(n + 1):
    table.append([])
    for j in range(m + 1):
        table[i].append(0)

for row in range(1, n + 1):
    for col in range(1, m + 1):
        left = table[row][col - 1] - 1
        up = table[row - 1][col] - 1
        upLeft = table[row - 1][col - 1] + s(seq1[col - 1], seq2[row - 1])
        table[row][col] = max(left, up, upLeft)
return table[n][m]) / (n + m)
```

[image: Reference cycle in table]

Comment: Why do you think the code leaks memory? Do you force garbage collection? Do you force Python to release the memory back to the operating system?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, I'm trying to use gc but find no items or may by not working properly. My problem now is how to fast derefer max(left, up, upLeft).

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that that code is leaking memory.  But it's hard to tell what is causing your problem without knowing what's going on here.  For example: What is `s`? What are `seq1` and `seq2`? What are the values of m and n?

Comment: I tell You what leaking, it is list of list refer inside. table is list of lists

Comment: I don't see any evidence that your code would cause a memory leak.

Comment: If it is indeed still referenced, then you should be able to dereference the element in question by `table[row][col] = max(left, up, upLeft)[0]`.  However, I suspect that changing the statement in this way will result in an IndexError, since max should return a scalar value.

Comment: yup I have:  "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
Added screen shot from PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "leaking"? Are you referring to the fact that your algorithm uses more memory than expected? If this is the case, then it could be related to your table definition  vs. its usage: you're allocating an n x m table, whereas you're using just (n-1) x (m-1) items.
Try changing your loops from `range(1, n+1)` to `range(n)`, making the similar change for the second index (and updating the index usages of course).

Comment: Why change range parameter? It works now and I don't think that changing it can prevent leaking. I mean that memory still allocated after return value. If I replace max(...) with zero or sth memory usage grows slower and had been freed at return (when table is not reachable).